# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { - Error while running protractor cucumber test

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am just trying to start with Protractor- Cucumber test setup and following is my basic setup that I did following some tutorials online. Thanks to the Samaritan who shared that.

The problem is that when I try to run it, I get the error - unexpected token for the imports. I have no clue as why its giving that. Any help is much appreciated.

Following are the versions of node etc I am using -

```
C:\Users\A>npm --version
6.4.1

C:\Users\A>node --version
v10.15.1

C:\Users\A>protractor --version
Version 5.4.2
```

Following is my feature file -

```
Feature: Go to the home
  Display the title

  Scenario: Home Page
    Given I am on the home page
    When I do nothing
    Then I should see the title
```

Following is my steps definition file -

```
import { AppPage } from '../pages/app.po';
import { Before, Given, When, Then } from 'cucumber';
import { expect } from 'chai';

let page: AppPage;

Before(() => {
  page = new AppPage();
});

Given(/^I am on the home page$/, async () => {
  await page.navigateTo();
});

When(/^I do nothing$/, () => {});

Then(/^I should see the title$/, async () => {
  expect(await page.getTitleText()).to.equal('Welcome to angular-cli-cucumber-demo!');
});
```

Following is my page objects file -

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getTitleText() {
    return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
  }
}
```

I am getting below error when I try running tests using command `ng e2e` -

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56273/devtools/browser/7653bd59-c490-4ac0-a00e-0d3132dc5b11
[0417/123615.432:ERROR:broker_win.cc(137)] Error sending sync broker message: Error (0x5) while retrieving error. (0xE8)
[0417/123615.433:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(92)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
[12:36:17] E/launcher - Error: C:\Users\A527629\Documents\workspace-vs-code\poc-serenity\e2e\src\steps\app.steps.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { AppPage } from '../pages/app.po';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at supportCodePaths.forEach.codePath (C:\Users\A527629\Documents\workspace-vs-code\poc-serenity\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cli\index.js:142:42)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Cli.getSupportCodeLibrary (C:\Users\A527629\Documents\workspace-vs-code\poc-serenity\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cli\index.js:142:22)
    at C:\Users\A527629\Documents\workspace-vs-code\poc-serenity\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cli\index.js:169:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\A527629\Documents\workspace-vs-code\poc-serenity\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cli\index.js:44:103)
[12:36:17] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following section to your `protractor.conf.js`

```
onPrepare() {
  require('ts-node').register({
    project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
  });
}
```

Comment: this is the actual solution over all the above mentioned comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

**steps definition**

```
import { Before, Given, When, Then } from 'cucumber';
import { expect } from 'chai';
```

and 
**page objects**

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
```

These imports should be completed by protractor automatically when it initializes.

Comment: `Cannot find name 'AppPage', Cannot find name 'Given'.` and same for others.

Comment: You will still need the appPage import as you have created that page yourself, not sure about the issue with `Given`. Could you try changing to the require syntax `let AppPage = require('../pages/app.po');` first and then seeing how it behaves

Comment: `const AppPage = require('../pages/app.po');
const Before = require('cucumber');` this gets away the error and I am yet to test it, but any idea why the other one isn't working?

Comment: I take it you are using javascript and not typescript?

Comment: Its an angualar 7 project, so no way Javascript.

Comment: You could have your test files in javascript despite your project being in ts. The reason I ask is because that syntax of imports is not natively supported in NodeJS. If you are using typsescript though your code should be getting transpiled down into javascript so that the `import from` syntax is usable. I'm not sure if this is the case for straight JS files. Note: I could be mistaken about some of this but that is my understanding

Comment: Getting `[18:00:53] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module '../pages/app.po'` with this syntax.

Comment: Can you verify if that path is correct to your file?

Comment: Yeah, I got away with the error `cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register'   // interpret step definitions as TypeScript
  },`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, changing imports with require worked but after that I had same issue with static readonly constants.

Comment: @apun Did you find the solution?

Comment: @SanjaPaskova, No. I had dropped using it. I shifted to cypress instead of protractor now.